# PHP SVN functions

Tags: php, svn

I've just discovered http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.svn.php, which is actually what I've been looking for for a while.

I am able to use svn_ls to correctly list directories and their files, which is perfect, but for the next part of my S3 deployment script, I need to be able to use `svn_fs_file_contents`. Unfortunately, I am unable to correctly getting it working. It says it needs a resource, but even with experimenting, I am unable to get it working.

Has anyone used these functions before and got a basic working script together that enables you to pull file contents, etc?

This would be a huge help, any point in the right direction is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you have direct access to the repository (i.e. to the underlying file system)?

Comment: No, I am using www.beanstalkapp.com

Comment: From what I understand the `svn_fs_*` function would require you to have direct access (disclaimer: I've never used the extension). Anyway, why can't you just use `file_get_contents('http://...')`?

Comment: wow, I think I am actually being an idiot. I probably can just use file_get_contents once I've been able to list the dir. You are probably right again about the svn_fs_* functions being unusable due to not having direct access to the file system.

Comment: Beware the http wrapper does not support digest authentication; you'll have to use curl or... handle it manually (if the server indeed uses digest authentication).

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on the docs, it seems that you'd need to do a few things first:

```
$repository = svn_repos_open('svn://server/path/to/svn');
$fs = svn_repos_fs($repository);
$file = svn_fs_file_contents($fs, 'path/to/file');
```

But, let me ask you these questions.  Why do you need read/write access to svn?  Can you get away with using system calls (`exec('svn update');`)?  Can you get away with using [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) access to the repository?